# How to calculate effect size for categorical variables between unequal groups

Tags: r

I have a large data set of ~80,000. I'm performing a series of multiple regressions and keeping the default argument to omit NAs (I'm on a tight deadline and poor computational power so no time for multiple imputation).

This means that e.g. for one outcome I have ~50000 observations. I want to check that these 50000 don't vastly differ to the other 30000 in terms of each variable of interest.

Due to the large N I think using a test of effect size would be better than significance.
In R I've performed individual Cohen's D tests on each continuous variable with a Cohen's D function I've found e.g.

```
cohensd(completecases$age, incompletecases$age)
```

but how do I handle the categorical variables?

The phi coefficient isn't suitable as some of my factors have more than 2 levels (e.g. ethnicity has white, black, asian, mixed). I also looked at Cramer's V but this requires my samples (complete and incomplete) to be the same size.
What test of effect size can I perform on categorical variables of more than 2 levels, in unequal groups?

All I can think is to create a new variable indicating sample membership and performing a logistic regression of e.g. ethnicity ~ membership

Comment: You can use the `phi` coefficient from `sjstats`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sjstats/versions/0.16.0/topics/phi

Comment: As I said in the post, I have more than 2 levels for some factors ("Phi coefficient for 2x2 tables") and Cramer's V ("for nominal variables with more than 2 categories") requires the same N in each group. Unless I'm missing something?